# An error occurred while installing mini_racer (0.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to deploy the ruby on rails application on elastic beanstalk using cloud9 ubuntu server. I'm using awseb-cli for deploying
I'm able to connect to my elastic beanstalk environment and also ssh into the ec2 instance, means my eb status and eb ssh are working, but when I ran eb deploy i got this error,

```
eb deploy
Alert: Your environment is using a deprecated platform branch. It might not be supported in the future.

Alert: The platform version that your environment is using isn't recommended. There's a recommended version in the same platform branch.

Creating application version archive "app-edbc-210709_230802".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
2021-07-09 23:08:16    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2021-07-09 23:08:23    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2021-07-09 23:08:47    ERROR   [Instance: i-0fed7784c6a4ae86e] Command failed on instance. Return code: 5 Output: (TRUNCATED).../extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/mini_racer-0.4.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing mini_racer (0.4.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install mini_racer -v '0.4.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  mini_racer. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
2021-07-09 23:08:47    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2021-07-09 23:08:47    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0fed7784c6a4ae86e'. Aborting the operation.
2021-07-09 23:08:47    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.        
                                                                      
ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

Here is the Gem

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
# gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
rails_version = "~> 5.1.4"
gem "activesupport",  rails_version
gem  "actionpack",    rails_version
gem  "actionview",    rails_version
gem  "activemodel",   rails_version
gem  "activerecord",  rails_version
gem  "activejob",     rails_version
gem  "actioncable",   rails_version
gem  "railties",      rails_version

gem "sprockets-rails", ">= 2.0.0"
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
# gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'dotenv-rails'
gem 'mimemagic', github: 'mimemagicrb/mimemagic', ref: '01f92d86d15d85cfd0f20dabd025dcbd36a8a60f'
gem 'awesome_print', require: 'ap'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'fog-aws'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'rqrcode'
gem 'devise'
gem 'faker'
gem 'kaminari'
gem "chartkick"
gem 'groupdate'
gem 'rubyzip', require: 'zip'
gem 'pdfkit', require: 'pdfkit'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'best_in_place', '~> 3.0.1'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'zip_tricks'
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.1'
gem "cocoon"
gem "font-awesome-rails"
gem 'devise_invitable', github: 'scambra/devise_invitable'
gem 'invisible_captcha'
gem 'mini_racer'
gem 'exception_notification'
gem 'copy_carrierwave_file'

##SMS stuff
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'whenever'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: What is it saying in `/var/log/eb-activity.log` on the server?